# How do I train a Gater using custom inputs?

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am trying to use keras to create a mixture of SVMs based on the paper Bengio et all.

I have trained two svm classifiers with their outputs as svm1, svm2. I have written a pseudo code below.

```
def mlp_model(svm1,svm2):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=54))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Merge([model, svm1, svm2], output_shape=(2,), mode=merge_mode))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def merge_mode(branches):
    g, svm1, svm2 = branches
    return K.transpose(K.transpose(svm1) * g[:, 0] + K.transpose(svm2) * g[:, 1])
```

My question

- How do I add custom inputs to my model. (in this case y_hats from svm experts)?